# Theorem style 'bodyfont' not respected

Tags: theorems

The two theorem styles below which differ at `bodyfont` style, give the same font style. Can someone help on this?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts,color,graphicx,xcolor}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\declaretheoremstyle[
    headfont=\bfseries,
    notebraces={(}{)},
    bodyfont=\normalfont\scshape,
    headpunct={},
    postheadspace=\newline,
    postheadhook={\textcolor{red}{\rule[2.0ex]{\linewidth}{0.8pt}}\\},
    spacebelow=\parsep,
    spaceabove=\parsep,
    mdframed={
        backgroundcolor=cyan!20,
            linecolor=red!30,
            innertopmargin=6pt,
            roundcorner=5pt,
            innerbottommargin=6pt,
            skipbelow=\parsep,
            skipbelow=\parsep }
]{myexamplestyle}

% example environment - thmtools
\declaretheorem[
    style=myexamplestyle,
    name=EEEEE,
    numberwithin=section
    %qed=$\Box$
]{EE}

\declaretheoremstyle[
    headfont=\bfseries,
    notebraces={(}{)},
    bodyfont=\normalfont\itshape,
    headpunct={},
    postheadspace=\newline,
    postheadhook={\textcolor{cyan}{\rule[2.0ex]{\linewidth}{0.8pt}}\\},
    spacebelow=\parsep,
    spaceabove=\parsep,
    mdframed={
        backgroundcolor=green!20,
            linecolor=magenta!30,
            innertopmargin=6pt,
            roundcorner=5pt,
            innerbottommargin=6pt,
            skipbelow=\parsep,
            skipbelow=\parsep }
]{myexamplestyle}

% example environment - thmtools
\declaretheorem[
    style=myexamplestyle,
    name=DDDDDD,
    numberwithin=chapter
]{DD}
\begin{document}
\begin{EE}
Some text.
\end{EE}

\begin{DD}
The other text
\end{DD}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What's the question? Avoiding the repetition of the style specification?

Comment: @Ahmad Omar I have shortened your title and moved the question in to the body of the question to better fit the style of this site.  Please edit if the wording is not to your liking.

Answer (score 2):

You need to give the two styles different names:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts,color,graphicx,xcolor}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\declaretheoremstyle[
    headfont=\bfseries,
    notebraces={(}{)},
    bodyfont=\normalfont\scshape,
    headpunct={},
    postheadspace=\newline,
    postheadhook={\textcolor{red}{\rule[2.0ex]{\linewidth}{0.8pt}}\\},
    spacebelow=\parsep,
    spaceabove=\parsep,
    mdframed={
        backgroundcolor=cyan!20,
            linecolor=red!30,
            innertopmargin=6pt,
            roundcorner=5pt,
            innerbottommargin=6pt,
            skipbelow=\parsep }
]{myexamplestyle}

% example environment - thmtools
\declaretheorem[
    style=myexamplestyle,
    name=EEEEE,
    numberwithin=section
    %qed=$\Box$
]{EE}

\declaretheoremstyle[
    headfont=\bfseries,
    notebraces={(}{)},
    bodyfont=\normalfont\itshape,
    headpunct={},
    postheadspace=\newline,
    postheadhook={\textcolor{cyan}{\rule[2.0ex]{\linewidth}{0.8pt}}\\},
    spacebelow=\parsep,
    spaceabove=\parsep,
    mdframed={
        backgroundcolor=green!20,
            linecolor=magenta!30,
            innertopmargin=6pt,
            roundcorner=5pt,
            innerbottommargin=6pt,
            skipbelow=\parsep }
]{mysecondexamplestyle}

% example environment - thmtools
\declaretheorem[
    style=mysecondexamplestyle,
    name=DDDDDD,
    numberwithin=chapter
]{DD}
\begin{document}
\begin{EE}
Some text.
\end{EE}

\begin{DD}
The other text
\end{DD}
\end{document}
```

In the above the first `theoremstyle` is labelled `myexamplestyle` as in your code, the second I have changed to `mysecondexamplesytle` to avoid overlap.  Such renaming is not always necessary, but it is good practice.  Testing examples shows that repeated declaration of the same style name behaves rather unpredictably.

Your example code fails to load the `mdframed` package.  Adding this to the code removes some warnings.  To get the round effect on the corners of the boxes you also need to specify `tikz` as a `framemethod`.  Adding the line

```
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
```

then produces

[image: Sample output rounded]

which may be is more what you intended.

I have removed a repeated `skipbelow` in your `mdframed` specification.  It is possible you meant one of these to be `skipabove`.